# Why doesn't this program write in result.txt?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "vettore.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    FILE *result = fopen("result.txt", "w");
    int cont = 0, i, n;
    char *s1;
    if(argc != 1)
        printf("Numero parametri non corretto\n");
    else{
        FILE *fp = fopen("test_suite.txt", "r");
        while(fscanf(fp, "%s %d", s1, &n) == 2)
            cont++;
        rewind(fp);
        for(i=0; i<cont; i++){
            fscanf(fp, "%s %d", s1, &n);
            int *a = (int*) calloc(n, sizeof(int));
            char *s2;
            strcpy(s2, s1);
            finput_array(strcat(s1,"_input.txt"), a, n);
            strcpy(s1,s2);
            bubblesort(a, n);
            foutput_array(strcat(s1, "_output.txt"), a, n);
            strcpy(s1,s2);
            int *oracle = (int*) calloc(n, sizeof(int));
            finput_array(strcat(s1, "_oracle.txt"), oracle, n);
            strcpy(s1,s2);

            if(confronta_array(a, oracle, n))
                fprintf(result, "%s PASS\n", s1);
            else
                fprintf(result, "%s FAIL\n", s1);
            free(a);
            free(oracle);
        }
        fclose(fp);
    }
    fclose(result);
}
```

This are "vettore.c" functions:

```
void bubblesort(int a[], int n){
int i, j;
  for(i = 0 ; i < n - 1; i++)
  {
    for(j = 0 ; j < n - i - 1; j++)
    {
      if (a[j] > a[j+1]) /* For decreasing order use < */
      {
        scambia(&a[j], &a[j+1]);
       }
      }
     }
}

void finput_array(char *file_name, int a[], int n){
    FILE *fd = fopen(file_name, "r");
    if(fd == NULL)
        printf("Errore in apertura del file %s\n", file_name);
    else{
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
            fscanf(fd, "%d", &a[i]);
        fclose(fd);
    }
}

void foutput_array(char *file_name, int a[], int n){
    int i;
    FILE *fd;

    fd = fopen(file_name, "w");
    if(fd == NULL)
        printf("Errore in apertura del file %s\n", file_name);
    else{
        for(i=0; i<n; i++)  
            fprintf(fd, "%d\n", a[i]);
        fclose(fd);
    }
}

int confronta_array(int a[], int b[], int n){
    int i=0;

    while(i<n && a[i] == b[i])
        i++;

    return (i==n) ? 1 : 0;
}
```

The program doesn't write anything in "result.txt". Why?

It should write those sentences.

Comment: We would need a [mcve] to be sure, but the most plausible explanation I see is that the `for` loop performs zero iterations.  That might easily result from the contents of the `test_suite.txt` file being malformed.

Comment: Where do you make `s1` point to enough memory to hold the string you try to read into what it points to?

Comment: @JohnBollinger it contains "TC1 1
TC2 9
TC3 10
TC4 12"

Comment: On the other hand, perhaps the program just crashes.  It is, after all, trying to `strcpy` into the memory pointed to by `s2`, when in fact `s2` has never been assigned a value.  The program therefore having undefined behavior, pretty much anything might happen.

Comment: Same with `s2`. Always compile with warnings and debug information turned on! Then run your program through valgrind, or compile with [ASan](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizer).

Comment: I declared s1 and s2 as s1[20] and s2[20] and now it works.

Comment: Spam-repeating the same thing over and over because you didn't explain well enough doesn't mean that you did explain well enough. You may have fooled the content screening filter, but you haven't fooled us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this part:

```
while(fscanf(fp, "%s %d", s1, &n) == 2) cont++;
```

Maybe "cont" dont increment because "test_suite.txt" don't have the "fscanf" format requirements.